# PostgreSQL 13 - Performance Improvement to delete large table data

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, database-administration

I am using PostgreSQL 13 and has intermediate level experience with PostgreSQL.

I have a table named `tbl_employee`. it stores employee details for number of customers.

Below is my table structure, followed by datatype and index access method

```
  Column     |            Data Type        |     Index name            | Idx Access Type
-------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------
 id          | bigint                      |                           |
 name        | character varying           |                           | 
 customer_id | bigint                      |  idx_customer_id          | btree
 is_active   | boolean                     |  idx_is_active            | btree
 is_delete   | boolean                     |  idx_is_delete            | btree
```

I want to delete employees for specific customer by customer_id.

In table I have total 18,00,000+ records.

When I execute below query for `customer_id` `1001` it returns 85,000.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_employee WHERE customer_id=1001;`

When I perform delete operation using below query for this customer then it takes 2 hours, 45 minutes to delete the records.

`DELETE FROM tbl_employee WHERE customer_id=1001`

**Problem**

My concern is that this query should take less than 1 min to delete the records. Is this normal to take such long time or is there any way we can optimise and reduce the execution time?

Below is Explain output of delete query

[image]

The values of `seq_page_cost = 1` and `random_page_cost = 4`.

Below are no.of pages occupied by the table "tbl_employee" from pg_class.

[image]
Please guide. Thanks

Comment: Any foreign keys referencing that table?

Comment: Please add the actual definition for the table to the question, including FKs. ( `\d+ tbl_employee` in psql is a start) BTW: do you really have indexes on boolean columns?)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No there is no any foreign keys

Comment: @wildplasser i don't have any FKs on my table also the customer_id is not FK . And yes i have index on Boolean columns it's for other use

Comment: We'd need `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to be certain what is going on. If there are no foreign keys pointing to the table, perhaps there are too many indexes or triggers.

Comment: Any table or row lock while you try to delete these records?

Comment: Not relevant here, but and index on a boolean column is unlikely to be helpful if `true` and `false` are both common in the data. And if one is unusual but of interest, a partial index on the PK using `WHERE is_delete IS TRUE` or something similar would be more likely to speed up queries.

Answer (score 0):

During :

```
DELETE FROM tbl_employee WHERE customer_id=1001
```

Is there any other operation accessing this table?  If only this SQL accessing this table,  I don't think it will take so much time.

Comment: No there is no other operation while deleting data from this table

Comment: Thanks.  What about the column : id?  Is it the primary key? 
And,  do you mind dropping the index of: idx_is_active    and idx_is_delete? 
And then:
 reindex tbl_employee 
then execute delete again?

Comment: To make the batch delete smaller, you can try this:

         DELETE FROM tbl_employee WHERE ctid IN (SELECT ctid FROM tbl_employee where customer_id=1001 limit 1000)

Until there is nothing to delete. Here the "ctid" is an internal column of Postgresql Tables. It can locate the rows.

Answer (score 0):

In RDBMS systems each SQL statement is also a [transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html), unless it's wrapped in `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;` to make multi-statement transactions.

It's possible your multirow DELETE statement is generating a very large transaction that's forcing PostgreSQL to thrash -- to spill its transaction logs from RAM to disk.

You can try repeating this statement until you've deleted all the rows you need to delete:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_employee WHERE customer_id=1001 LIMIT 1000;
```

Doing it this way will keep your transactions smaller, and may avoid the thrashing.

Answer (score 0):

SQL:  `DELETE FROM tbl_employee WHERE customer_id=1001 LIMIT 1000;`
will not work then.

To make the batch delete smaller, you can try this:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_employee WHERE ctid IN (SELECT ctid FROM tbl_employee where customer_id=1001 limit 1000)
```

Until there is nothing to delete.
Here the "ctid" is an internal column of Postgresql Tables. It can locate the rows.